# Subclass method signature inference

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following abstract class

```
// AbstractFiller.ts
export abstract class AbstractFiller {
   public abstract fill(data: number | string | boolean | Date, numberOfFillers: number): string;
}
```

and several filler subclasses

```
export class WhiteSpacesFiller extends AbstractFiller {
  public fill(data: number | string | boolean | Date, numberOfFillers: number): string {
    // logic
  }
}

export class ZerosFiller extends AbstractFiller {
  public fill(data: number | string | boolean | Date,  numberOfFillers: number): string {
    // logic
  }
}

// ...etc
```

Is there a way that TS would infer the method signature from the abstract class so that I have:

1. No type duplication in every subclass
2. Strict signature enforcing e.g. removing `number` from the type of `data` in a subclass will **not** throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript will not infer method parameters from base class. The way it works is that after the class is typed, the class is checked for compatibility with the base class. This mean that a parameter in a derived class can be of a derived type (this is not sound but class method parameters relate bivariantly even under strict null checks).

One thing that can be done to reduce the amount of type duplication is to use `Parameters` with rest parameter destructuring.

```
export abstract class AbstractFiller {
    public abstract fill(data: number | string | boolean | Date, numberOfFillers: number): string;
}

export class WhiteSpacesFiller extends AbstractFiller {
    public fill(...[data, numberOfFillers]: Parameters<AbstractFiller['fill']>): string {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the .answer. Hmm, that's interesting. Didn't know you can do it like this. Is this a common approach? Any issues you have encountered with this approach?

Comment: @RolandJegorov have not used it much myself...but it should work.. if you have any issues let me know. I am certain there is no other way though :)

Comment: Alright, thanks. I will keep this open for a day or two and then if nothing else comes up, accept your answer. :)

Comment: Also, just to add to the strict signature enforcing point I wrote above, it seems that any type of an argument will be valid as long as it's a subset of the abstract classes method signature. `string | number and string` I hope I explained it clear enough.

Comment: @RolandJegorov Yes, that is true, there is no way to prevent that unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me if I misunderstand the question, but I think you can solve your problem with generics i.e. have your `AbstractFiller` class be generic.

That would look something like this:

```
export abstract class AbstractFiller<T> {
    public abstract fill(data: T, numberOfFillers: number): string;
}

export class WhiteSpacesFiller extends AbstractFiller<string> {
    public fill(data: string, numberOfFillers: number) {
        //logic
        return data;
    }
} 

export class ZerosFiller extends AbstractFiller<number> {
    public fill(data: number, numberOfFillers: number) {
        return data.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. My point was more to be able to do something like 
`public fill(data, numberOfFillers)`. Also, here it seems that the duplication was moved rather than eliminated.